# How to connect mysql database in .Net

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to .Net, in which I have written a controller such that is

```
 public class StudentController : Controller
{        
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And a model class like following

```
public class Students
{

    public int id{ get; set;}
    public String name{ get; set; }
    public int age{ get; set; }

}
```

And I have created a table named student in mysql database. Now I want to get the data from the table, but I don't know how to connect to a mysql DB in .Net

Please anybody help with some example code

Comment: what do you try so far? did you try searching for "mysql c# .net connect" ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tutorial to connect to mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html

hope it helps

Edited :

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
string myConnectionString;

myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;" +
     "pwd=12345;database=test;";

try
{
    conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
    conn.Open();
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: edited :D Better? Cheers :D

Answer (score 0):

Download the MySQLConnector. You can download it from below URL.
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net

After that you can use Entity Framework to connect with your database. So you can retrieve data from your database.

Please check this [tutorial](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/articles/tutorial_ef.html)